# Finding Number of Items Present on Given Date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a series of start dates and end dates like so:

```
01/03/2015    01/07/2016            
01/04/2015    01/04/2016
02/05/2015    04/08/2016
```

What I'd like to be able to do is count how many in this series were active on a given date. In this example, the count would be 3 as of say 05/05/2015. How can I do this for many dates without double counting?

Comment: Why do you say double counting? Please share what have you tried.

Answer (score 1):

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A3<A7),--(B1:B3>A7))`
A1:A3 starting range and B1:B3 ending range and A7 is the given date, -- before range to evaluate true to 1 so it can be added to give the count of active series.

> Also another method, you can use Countifs like the following:
>      =COUNTIFS(A1:A3,"<"&A7,B1:B3,">"&A7)